# open popup on long click of action bar

Tags: android

[image: right now it is showing like this. when I click on actionbar any where then it shows only at left corner. I want it to open below i click]I want to show the popup menu on longer click of action bar **but exactly below where I click**.

```
toolbar.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(HomeActivity.this,toolbar);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.device_setting:
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "dev settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.app_update:
                        break;
                    case R.id.wireless_setting:
                        break;
                    case R.id.hide_footer:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

and `popup_menu.xml` is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/device_setting"
        android:title="Device Setting"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/app_update"
        android:title="App Update"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/wireless_setting"
        android:title="Wireless Setting"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/hide_footer"
        android:title="Full Screen"></item>
</menu>
```

screen shot is given below.
I want to open popup exactly below where I click (longer click)on `ActionBar`. Please help

[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZiCc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, you just need to use the popup window because is very flexible, I prefer this GitHub library
https://github.com/kakajika/RelativePopupWindow

Here, just need to change the position of the window for example

```
popup.showOnAnchor(toolbar, VerticalPosition.BELOW, HorizontalPosition.LEFT);
```

Comment: thanx for the help. but it is for above API 21, I want this functionality from API 19 to above

Comment: can you check this library documentation one more time because this library give support to API 9+